# UIView class has too many delegate methods to parent View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, oop, model-view-controller, delegates

I'm a bit of a newbie programmer, so I'm asking for people's opinions/advice on what they would do in the situation I'm in.

**Background**

Due to constraints of the library I'm using to achieve a "pop up" like window, I'm currently working on a UIView class (let's call it `Menu`) which creates `UIImagePickers` and various other View Controllers (`VCs`). However, since the UIView itself persists on top of any VCs it spawns itself, I'm forced to delegate any VC creation methods to the parentVC of `Menu`, so that I can dismiss the `Menu` view, create any VCs necessary, and then (sometimes) additionally restore the `Menu` view.

**Issue**

I'm currently copy and pasting hundreds of lines of delegate methods for any UIViewController that has a `Menu` view. These delegate methods are the same for every one of those view controllers, and exist there because the methods have `UIViewController` specific functions such as `presentViewController`. I'm tempted to pass the parentVC as a parameter to `Menu` in order to cut down on the amount of duplicate code, but this seems MVC-unkosher. What would be a good approach to this problem?

Comment: Create `MainViewController` and then subclass it. In `MainViewController` implement all methods you need.

Comment: Since you are using Swift, you can adopt protocol oriented programming; create an extension that implements all of your delegate methods and then you can simply adopt this extension in any view controller that needs it. This is similar to using a subclass but is more flexible as you can adopt multiple extensions(protocols) as required

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you can Just create an extension, like this

```
extension SomeClass: ClassesDelegates {
    //some specific code that all Views will use
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm tempted to pass the parentVC as a parameter to Menu in order to cut down on the amount of duplicate code, but this seems MVC-unkosher.

That's because MVC is a dated architectural choice, leading to exactly this kind of situation. That's where the "Massive View Controller" snark that you may have noticed here and there around the web comes from.

Your `Menu` depends on parentVC. Thus, we call parentVC a dependency. A fundamental precept of modern architectures is **dependency injection**, which allows you to eliminate the duplicate code you refer to and test `Menu` in isolation from its dependencies. Check out

- [Dependency Injection Demystified](http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html)
- [Dependency Injection](https://www.objc.io/issues/15-testing/dependency-injection/)
- [Dependency Injection, iOS and You](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/dependency-injection-ios/)
- [Dependency Injection in Swift](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/dependency-injection-in-swift-a959c6eee0ab#.omygtqhsw)

So, fear not the use of parameters, your instincts are sound. Embrace the use of parameters, and preen that you are adopting the "25-dollar term for a 5-cent concept" (see first link), the Agile design pattern referred to as ***Dependency Injection***. For bonus cool points, do not make that parameter a UIViewController. Define a protocol with just the access that `Menu` requires, and make that parameter anything that conforms to said protocol, and add an extension to UIViewController conforming to that protocol. That makes testing and reuse elsewhere easier; and more importantly, then you will be engaging in *Protocol-Oriented Programming,* which puts you right out on the cutting edge of trendy Swift design patterns. Nobody will call you a newbie then.